# Is every real $\in(0,1)$ between the reciprocals of two consecutive integers?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\alpha $ be a real number such that $0 < \alpha < 1 $. Does there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that

$$ \frac{1}{n+1} \leq \alpha < \frac{1}{n} $$

??

I guess this follows from the Archimedean property, but I don't see how to justify this formally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We want to find integer $n$ such that $n\alpha < 1$ but $(n+1)\alpha \geq 1$. Consider the set
$$
S=\{k\in\mathbb{N}: k\alpha\geq 1\}
$$
By Archimedean property, the set $S$ is non-empty. Pick the minimal element of $S$, and call it $m$. And let $n=m-1$. Then it is easy to check that $(n+1)\alpha = m\alpha\geq 1$, but $n\alpha=(m-1)\alpha<1$.

Comment: One should check that $m\neq 1$.

Comment: And this is why constructing the real numbers from Peano systems at least once is an important exercise for students. It's the best way to understand and therefore master the properties of the reals,particularly the various implications of the Archimedean property.

Comment: @user7530: Good point. Since $\alpha<1$ and $m\in S$, we know that $m>m\alpha\geq 1$, so $m>1$.

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 although I prefer the axiom that $\mathbb{N}$ is well-ordered (put to great use in this answer) over the usual clunky axiom of induction.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**: $n = \lfloor \dfrac{1}{\alpha}\rfloor$